# Verfiy/Test Acknowledgment was called in spring boot kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, mockito

I've written integration tests for my Spring Boot Kafka (Consumer/Producer) service everything gone well. So I'm committing the offsets of my consumer manually after some processing.
**I want to verify whether `acknowledgment.acknowledge()` was called in the consumer. Is is to possible verify?**

Here is my method signature of the service:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {TOPIC_XXX_V1}, containerFactory = "XXXListener")
    private void consumer(@Payload XXXXRequestEvent xxxxRequestEvent, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

.....
// do something with the database

acknowledgment.acknowledge()
```

For the testing side I'm using `@SpyBean` for the Service and a `MockBean` for the database interaction. I want verify somehow whether in the test case the `.acknowledge()` was called. FYI: the `.acknowledge()` is a public abstract void method

Comment: Can you add the infrastructure setup for your integration test? Do you start a local Kafka for your test?

Comment: I use Testcontainers

Answer (score 1):

As the `Acknowledge` instance is injected and created as part of Spring Kafka when consuming a message, I guess there is no way to use something like `verify()` of Mockito for this.

When writing a unit test instead you could pass a mocked version of `Acknowledge` here and then verify that this method was invoked. However, with a unit test, you can't test the actual consumption of a message (serialization, correct message handler, etc.).

So in your case, I would try to verify that your message was acknowledged by e.g. using Testcontainers to execute commands inside the Kafka container and ensuring that the already acknowledged message is not returned any more.

Another approach could be to create a Kafka client as part of your test and then try to consume messages from the same topic for X seconds and expect zero results. [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) might help you here.

Comment: Yeah was also thinking in this direction. I was think about using the KafkaAdminClient and get the lag of the consumerGroups.